# Insert code in header - but only on CMS page (Magento + Fancybox)

Tags: php, jquery, magento, header, fancybox

I need to insert this code in the header of one CMS page:

```
<!-- FancyBox Script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
```

First I inserted the code in the header (so it is on all pages on the site), but then the add to cart function didn't work. So I need the code to only appear on a specific CMS page where I need the Fancybox. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to do this in code?  I'd suggest doing this through the ADMIN system.  Simply switch to code view and paste it in.

Alternatively, create a module, and .phtml template file with this content, then add it to the page in the ADMIN using Layout XML updates.

If you edit the CMS Page you want to include Fancybox on, click on the `design` tab, and then include the following in the `Layout XML Update` section:

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="fancyboxcode">
        <action method="setText">
            <text>
                <![CDATA[
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
                ]]>
            </text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: I tried to add the code under the CMS page -> Content. But it didn't work properly, that's why I figured it need to be in the header because it loads first maybe? I don't know how to create a module as you describe - can you explain more how I do that?

Comment: Could you explain how to do what you described?

Comment: Updated my answer with code to add into the admin system.

Answer (score 0):

In the head.phtml file include your script withing this condition

```
<?php
if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms')
{ ?>


 // only if it is a CMS page

// Include your script here 

<?php } ?>
```

Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it, but the page won't load (blank page).

Comment: Its never good to hard code things in Magento. There are correct way of doing this, without having to hardcode.

Comment: check the matching of php tag you may missed the close tag.

Comment: I tried adding the code in header.phtml instead of head.phtml and it worked :)

Comment: Ok, a slight issue. Since the homepage is considered a cms page, the slider on my homepage stopped working. Can I make the code only work on that specific cms page and not cms pages in general?

Comment: Yes, by checking the cms identifier you can put this condition 
<?php $pageIdentifier = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier(); ?>
<?php if ($pageIdentifier == 'home'): ?>

Comment: How do I know what the page identifier is? And where excactly do I insert the code - before, after or within the other code?

Comment: In case of cms page in magento url key is the identifier.  Example : If http://www.example.com/about-us.html is the cms page url. then url key is about-us and .html is added as suffix to it.  
Answer to Second Question : you need to include you code withing if condition.   if ($pageIdentifier == 'home') { // your code will be here }

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you show me the complete code then? I don't know where to insert the condition for the page identifier. the url-key is 'hundebur-til-bilen'

Comment: I just tried adding this code: http://imgur.com/DW8KIHc - but it doesn't work (the script code is not loaded), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove { curly brackets as in if condition you are already using if(condition):
endif;

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in cms.xml =>  in theme layout folder.

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/caa-file-name.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]]></if></action>
</block>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want this header for home page only then you can use handler of home page in local.xml like

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="head">
         <block type="core/text" name="cdn.jquery">
            <action method="setText">
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
                    ]]>
                </text>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Now this will be loaded only on the homepage

Comment: I don't want it on the homepage - I want it only on a specific cms page :)